# Why is there is a gap between my looping images in my SpriteKit scene?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios9

At the beginning I have declared the nodes.

//Declaration of the ground nodes.

```
var groundImage: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var groundImage2: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
```

In the viewDidLoad I have:

```
    //Creates an instance of both sprites that are of the same image that are to be lined up against each other in the x axis creating the illution of continuity.

    groundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ground.png")
    groundImage2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ground.png")

    //Specifies the Z position of the images.

    groundImage.zPosition = 3
    groundImage2.zPosition = 3

    //Scales the images to the correct size of the screen.

    groundImage.size.width = self.frame.width
    groundImage.size.height = self.groundImage.size.height / 2

    groundImage2.size.width = self.frame.width
    groundImage2.size.height = self.groundImage2.size.height / 2

    //Specicies the x position of the images.  By offsetting the second you create the illution of a long, continuous image.

    groundImage.position.x = view.bounds.size.width * 0.5
    groundImage2.position.x = view.bounds.size.width * 1.5

    //Specifies the y postion of the images, obviously these are the same as they are not to be offset at any time.

    groundImage.position.y = (view.bounds.size.height - view.bounds.size.height) + self.groundImage.size.height / 2
    groundImage2.position.y = (view.bounds.size.height - view.bounds.size.height) + self.groundImage2.size.height / 2

    //Not sure what this does yet.

    groundImage.texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest
    groundImage2.texture?.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    //Adds instances of the sprites to the scene.

    self.addChild(groundImage)
    self.addChild(groundImage2)
```

In the update method I have:

```
    //This is how the image is moved relative the number specified.  The number in the variable is how many pixels the frame is being moved each frame refresh.

    groundImage.position.x -= gameSpeed
    groundImage2.position.x -= gameSpeed

    if (groundImage.position.x <= -self.view!.bounds.size.width / 2)
    {
        groundImage.position.x = self.view!.bounds.size.width * 1.5 // - 2
    }


    if (groundImage2.position.x <= -self.view!.bounds.size.width / 2)
    {
        groundImage2.position.x = self.view!.bounds.size.width * 1.5 // - 2
    }
```

Any yet there is a slight gap between the two images when they are looping.  This gap increases as I increase the speed they are looped at using a game speed variable.

Can anyone explain to me what I have done wrong please?

I have checked the images themselves are not causing the issue.

Thanks,

Steven

Comment: Why don't you use `SKAction` for this ?

Comment: The gap is probably because the update method called about 60 times in a second (defaults is 60 fps if I am not wrong), you should use `SKAction` to simply flip your images, it will be much more efficient.
Here is your starting point https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/AddingActionstoSprites/AddingActionstoSprites.html

Comment: Thankyou, this has helped.

Comment: No problems! Come again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gap is probably because the update method called about 60 times in a second (defaults is 60 fps if I am not wrong),
you should use `SKAction` to simply flip your images,
it will be much more efficient. Here is your starting point:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/AddingActionstoSprites/AddingActionstoSprites.html

Comment: This has helped but I'm still getting a slight line between images,  much smaller than before but still noticeable.  Any ideas?

Comment: oh... make the images 1 pixel larger.

Comment: To cover up the line - I had something like this... I think I used 3 images - I dont remmeber -- You can try really to make it larger pixel here pixel there.